# how to change default calendar odoo to jalali calendar in odoo 16

Tags: calendar, odoo, odoo-16, persian-calendar, jalali-calendar

I need to change default odoo 16 calendar to Jalali calendar.
I tried a lot, but I did not find a suitable module. Even if you introduce me to the documentation, I can develop a module for myself, but I don't know how to convert all Odoo calendars to Jalali.